# Fundamental-ness of fundamental forces

Tags: forces, black-holes, interactions, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

***Example*** :

Consider a black hole and it's event horizon of radius *R* surrounding it . Suppose in the direction of a diameter of the black hole ( or event horizon) , there are two charged particles. Distance between these particles is 4*R* . In order for each particle to experience an electromagnetic force from another, a photon must travel between them as an information carrier. But in the midway, the photon will be captured by black hole. *I conclude from this that the gravitational force of black hole affected the electromagnetic force between those two particles.*

***Question***

Then why do we even call these forces as fundamental as if they are able to affect other forces by affecting their carrier particles? Had I wrongly interpret the meaning of *fundamental* ?

Answer (score 1):

> Had I wrongly interpret the meaning of fundamental ?

For physics theories, yes you interpret wrongly.

The word "fundamental" in the way used in physics [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fundamental)

> a : serving as a basis supporting existence or determining essential structure or function : basic

In the present mainstream mathematical physics theories, the basic theory from which all others emerge is the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. It is the quantum field theory used for particles and is defined in dimensions of units compatible [with h_bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant#Reduced_Planck_constant) , the Planck constant, where the model's calculations are validated. That is where the fundamental forces are defined as such: basic forces in nature.

All other theories can be shown mathematically to *emerge* from this underlying level,  thermodynamics, maxwell classical electricity and magnetism, .... Though the forces are fundamental because everything, at present, is supposed to emerge from these, the forces measured in larger dimensions are composite, and do not invalidate the word fundamental for the quantum field theory of the standard model.

For simplicity, let us take a different example of a sphere than your black hole. Take an apple, and two charged particles across it. The fundamental forces are interactions of the charged particle with the surface of the apple, not with each other as there is a multitude of charges shielding one particle from the other.

Comment: Does that mean these four forces can interact with each other in non-quantum realms?

Comment: @Shiva In the classical domains forces do not interact, they are vectors that follow vector algebra.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused . Can you please tell what does "interact" means in physics?

Comment: in webster "mutual or reciprocal action or influence"  .  at the classical level the forces add or subtract. they do not affect each other. At the quantum level, proton proton interactions  for example , they add in complicated quantum mechanical ways, not vectorially.

Comment: So this mean vector addition is a different thing from interaction. Suppose that they "interacted" , then how we would know this?

Comment: By experiments. ? Behavior different than vector addition? I think it would show as non conservation of energy, and that law has been continually checked experimentally, that is why it is a law.

Comment: Hello, sorry once again. But it is getting so much technical. How conservation of energy would be not shown?  Again, I could not understand that how is vector addition different from interaction. Could you please tell any real life observable consequence if they were to interact? Thank you

Comment: The work done by the addition of two forces at the same time would not be equal to the addition of the individual work done  when they act sequentially  on the same mass each force, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics) .  You have to study the mathematics in order to understand, handwaving is not enough. let us stop this discussion here.